# Is there an AF_UNIX support on windows for Windows/WSL Interop on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, interop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, unix-socket

AF_UNIX sockets are supported on Windows starting in Windows Insider build 17093 (Windows 10 version 1803).
See [Windows/WSL Interop with AF_UNIX](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windowswsl-interop-with-af_unix/) blog post on the Windows Command Line blog.
There is any way to use it to Windows/WSL interop with two .NET Core app (client and server)
Thank you

Comment: I think you just need to detect the operating system and then start either the linux or window version of code.  See : https://mariusschulz.com/blog/detecting-the-operating-system-in-net-core

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think you didn’t understand my question. I would like to create a communication between a Linux process in WSL and a Windows process using AF_UNIX as presented in this blog post and I would like to know if it is supported in .NET on the Windows side

Comment: The connection is TCP which is a standard since the 1970's and is supported by both linux and windows.  Since you are running the code on a different operating system (version of Net) the c# code needs to be different.  So in your core app you implement both the windows and linux code and then depending where it is installed you use different instructions.

Comment: So you think it is not possible or less good than TCP to use a socket file like the C example shown in the blog post (currently in my project requests are sent dicrecly to wsl.exe as shell command but I think a client / server structure may be better)

Comment: We are talking two different Network Layers.  TCP is the transport layer and WSL is an application layer that uses TCP.   You question was about CORE.  I thought your question was the WSL Interop would it run on both Windows and CORE.  My answer was the c# code needed to be different (your link shows two versions) and that you can detect the Operating System so compiled code will work on both operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [UnixDomainSocketEndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.unixdomainsocketendpoint) class.

Also note that this only works on WSL version 1 and not version 2.

Here's a quick working sample I just cobbled together. Note that there's no real error-handling or robust input validation.

You'll need to either supply a path at the command line, create a c:\tmp\wsl directory, or edit the paths in the code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace AFUnixTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static UnixDomainSocketEndPoint _endpoint;
        static Socket UnixSocket => new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
        static bool IsLinux => RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux);
        static string _socketPath;
        static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _socketPath = IsLinux ? "/mnt/c/tmp/wsl/unix.sock" : "c:\\tmp\\wsl\\unix.sock";
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Usage();
                return;
            }
            if (args.Length > 1) _socketPath = args[1];
            _endpoint = new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(_socketPath);
            if (args[0].ToLower() == "-s")
            {
                Server();
            }
            else if (args[0].ToLower() == "-c")
            {
                Client();
            }
            else
            {
                Usage();
            }
        }

        static void Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage:");
            Console.WriteLine($"  { AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName } -s or -c [socket path]");
            Console.WriteLine($"    Socket path should be in { (IsLinux ? "Linux" : "Windows") } path format.");
        }

        static void Server()
        {
            if (File.Exists(_socketPath)) File.Delete(_socketPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
            using (Socket listener = UnixSocket)
            {
                listener.Bind(_endpoint);
                listener.Listen(10);
                using (Socket handler = listener.Accept())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesReceived = handler.Receive(_buffer);
                        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                        if (message.ToLower().StartsWith("exit")) break;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Received [{ message }].");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Exit received. Exiting...");
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Client()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting client. Enter text. \"Exit\" (without quotes) to quit.");
            using (Socket sender = UnixSocket)
            {
                sender.Connect(_endpoint);
                while (true)
                {
                    string message = Console.ReadLine();
                    var output = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    int bytesSent = sender.Send(output);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sent [{ bytesSent }] bytes.");
                    if (message.ToLower().StartsWith("exit")) break;
                }
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
        }
    }
}
```